# using windows environment path variables in cgo comments

Tags: c++, c, windows, bash, cgo

I can't seem to find a concrete answer for this question. I have been fiddling with a Cuda driver library that uses Cgo.  Of course on windows the Cuda toolkit gets installed and a `CUDA_PATH` variable gets created.  I would like to be able to call this path from the CGO file rather then writing the absolute path.

For instance:

`#cgo windows LDFLAGS:-L${CUDA_PATH}/x64` compared to `#cgo windows LDFLAGS: -LC:/cuda/v8.0/lib/x64`

So I've tried using the windows syntax `%CUDA_PATH%` and bash syntax `$CUDA_PATH`/`${CUDA_PATH}` and it doesn't seem to work.   I know that part of the problem is that cgo works off of the gcc compiler which probably accepts bash syntax over the weird windows syntax but I am also on a windows file system.

I have no doubt that calling a path variable would work fine on a linux machine or on OSX but I have been unable to make it work on windows.  I need to know if its possible to use windows environment variables in a cgo comment or do I need to continue to use an absolute path? And if it is possible, how should I go about doing it?  Do I need to add something to cygwin or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Is https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/ what you mean by "CGO"?

Comment: Search for SRCDIR in https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/

Comment: yes cgo is a way of calling c libraries in golang.

Comment: ${SRCDIR} indicates the absolute path of current go file not the absolute file path of the cuda library that I want to reference.  Even if I was to use ${SRCDIR} to find the relative path of the cuda library it still doesn't tell me if I can use the CUDA_PATH windows environment variable nor does it fix the problem.

Comment: I am a no-nothing in GO, but a quick scan of their documentation indicates to me that what you are trying to do, runs against one of their tenets, that all needed build configuration shall be contained in the source files.  I would be looking for a way to go get or install the cuda source into your project.

Comment: The problem with that is that you can't go get or install the cuda c libraries into the package.  Basically there are 9 versions and we write 2 flags for each so that the compiler will look into these paths but accessing the path variable instead would allow us to write only 2 flags that would work for all versions.

Comment: Seems like a problem you should take up with the creators of GO.  I think your other option might be to create some build process external to go that configures transient projects for each target from the same code repository.